# Rails/delayed job: not able to save model from within delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a Post model (below) which has a callback method to modify the body attribute via a delayed job.  If I remove "delay." and just execute #shorten_urls! instantly, it works fine.  However, from the context of a delayed job, it does NOT save the updated body.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :shorten_urls

  def shorten_urls
    delay.shorten_urls!
  end

  def shorten_urls!
    # this task might take a long time, 
    # but for this example i'll just change the body to something else
    self.body = 'updated body'
    save!
  end
end
```

Strangely, the job is processed without any problems:

```
[Worker(host:dereks-imac.home pid:76666)] Post#shorten_urls! completed after 0.0021
[Worker(host:dereks-imac.home pid:76666)] 1 jobs processed at 161.7611 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

Yet, the body is not updated.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

Per Alex's suggestion, I've updated the code to look like this (but to no avail):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :shorten_urls

  def self.shorten_urls!(post_id=nil)
    post = Post.find(post_id)
    post.body = 'it worked'
    post.save!
  end

  def shorten_urls
    Post.delay.shorten_urls!(self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Any answer on this? Currently experiencing the same problem ...

Comment: Any solutions? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @imderek Did you find a solution to this question?

Comment: What rails/delayed job versions?

Comment: I am on `rails 3.2.7` and `delayed_job 3.0.3` (with `delayed_job_active_record 0.3.2`). I finally got DJ to work (i.e. not only queue/dequeue the job, but actually execute it) by starting up my app with **Foreman** (obtained via the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) as opposed to **Passenger**. I have also found that restarting the server via the typical `touch tmp/restart.txt` is insufficient as far as getting the DJ process to pick up code changes; instead, I stop the Foreman processes (via `control-c`), and then run `foreman start` again. Please +1 if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons might be that `self` is not serialized correctly when you pass method to `delay`.  Try making `shorten_urls!` a class method that takes record id and fetches it from DB.

Comment: K, see my edit above.  I did what you suggested and, though it defies logic, it still doesn't update the post.